# Change password expiration date in Active Directory using VBS

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, passwords

I'm trying to change the password expiration date for a user in Active Directory using VBScript.  I have the code to obtain information about a user's password, but I can't find anything about how to change it.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
Const SEC_IN_DAY = 86400
Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &h10000

Set objOU = GetObject("LDAP://CN=[username],OU=Users,OU=New York,OU=NA,OU=[domain],DC=[domain],DC=firm")

intCurrentValue = objOU.Get("userAccountControl")

If intCurrentValue and ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD Then
  wscript.echo "The password does not expire."
Else
  dtmValue = objOU.PasswordLastChanged 
  Wscript.echo "The password was last changed on " & _
  DateValue(dtmValue) & " at " & TimeValue(dtmValue) & VbCrLf & _
  "The difference between when the password was last set" & VbCrLf & _
  "and today is " & int(now - dtmValue) & " days"
  intTimeInterval = int(now - dtmValue)

  Set objDomainNT = GetObject("WinNT://ropesgray")
  intMaxPwdAge = objDomainNT.Get("MaxPasswordAge")
  If intMaxPwdAge < 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "The Maximum Password Age is set to 0 in the " & _
      "domain. Therefore, the password does not expire."
  Else
    intMaxPwdAge = (intMaxPwdAge/SEC_IN_DAY)
    Wscript.echo "The maximum password age is " & intMaxPwdAge & " days"
    If intTimeInterval >= intMaxPwdAge Then
      Wscript.echo "The password has expired."
    Else
      Wscript.echo "The password will expire on " & _
      DateValue(dtmValue + intMaxPwdAge) & " (" & _
      int((dtmValue + intMaxPwdAge) - now) & " days from today" & ")."
    End If
  End If
End If


'strUserPrincipalName = objOU.Get("userPrincipalName")
'strSAMAccountName = objOU.Get("sAMAccountName")
'strMaxPWAge = objOU.Get("manager")

'WScript.Echo strUserPrincipalName
'WScript.Echo strSAMAccountName
'WScript.Echo strMaxPWAge
```

Comment: I have found the property that needs to be changed (I think): PasswordLastChanged, but I'm unable to set it.  I tried setting another property (zip code) and was able to set it using objUser.SetInfo, but when I try to set the date, the same line throws an error:                  objUser.Put "PasswordLastChanged", DateValue("31-Mar-11")
objUser.SetInfo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `pwdLastSet` attribute to change the password expiration, but perhaps not in the way you want. `pwdLastSet` is the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since 12:00 am January 1, 1601.
According to [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this attribute accepts only two values 0 or -1.

try this :

1. Set `pwdLastSet` to 0, this means that the password has never been set.
2. Then, Set `pwdLastSet` to -1, this means that the password has just been set. So the value that appears in `pwdLastSet` is the current date/time.

I use to use in in W2K3 and it's still working on W2H8 R2.

You can [find there a tool](http://www.silogix.fr/conversion-dentiers-64-bits-en-dates-relative-ou-absolue.aspx) (sorry in french) that allow you to create date/time from number of 100-nanosecond intervals since 12:00 am January 1, 1601.

**Be carefull** It lengthens the password duration, which is not good for security.

I hope it helps.

JP

Comment: Thanks JP - I've heard about the 0 and -1 values to alter this value, but can I set it to another number like you said?  (number of 100-nanosecond intervals since jan 1, 1601)  I would like to set the password to expire in 3 days.  Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: I think you can't set others value than (0, -1) in pwdLastSet. What do you exactly want to do ? Do you want to ask some users to retype their password in 3 days from a fixed date ?

Comment: I Would try to change accountExpires attribute, I'am going to test.

Comment: I would like to change the date a user's password expires or set the number of days until it expires.  So, for a given user - I wanna say "your password will expire in 3 days (or on 4/9/2011), so you have to change it at the time".  Thanks!  Keep in mind, I'm looking to change the password expiration date, not the account expiration date.

Comment: accountExpires is difinitly NOT the thing you need.

Comment: For me exists only 2 solutions. 1) compute the time from now to expiration time ([as explain here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323750/en-us)). 2) Set pwdLastSet to 0 to force user to change password.