# How to set password expiration date of Active Directory user

Tags: c#, vbscript, active-directory

I am writing an application that communicates with Active Directory and I need to test how it behaves when the password of a user account in Active Directory has only a few days until its expiration date.

Therefore my question is: how can I set the password expiration date of a particular Active Directory user account to a date like "today + 2 days" (without changing the password expiration policy, of course!). I am looking either for manual way to do that or a programmatic solution (e.g. VBScript or C# based).

I have already tried these two approaches:

- Set `pwdLastSet` using ADSIEdit. Problem: I can change the value only to 0. Other values are rejected with the error code 0x57 (Invalid argument).
- Using `IADsUser::PasswordExpirationDate`: Problem: setting `PasswordExpirationDate` fails with error code 0x800A01BD. (See code example below.)

Code example:

```
strUserName = "test97"
Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://CN=" & strUserName & ",CN=Users,DC=mydomain,DC=com")
dtmDate = Now+2
objUser.PasswordExpirationDate = dtmDate 
objUser.SetInfo
MsgBox "Successfully changed password expiration date"
```

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556806/change-password-expiration-date-in-active-directory-using-vbs)

Comment: @sternr: I already have read that Stack Overflow article. It doesn't solve my problem, and it seems to me that it also doesn't answer the question posed in that article. Reason: you can set pwdLastSet only to 0; therefore, pwdLastSet cannot be used to set a particular expiration date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. You can only mark the password as expired.

Answer (score 0):

The `PasswordExpirationDate` property is [readonly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677943(v=VS.85).aspx).

I might be wrong but I think your options are either to set the password to expired (by using the `pwdLastSet`), or by changing\shortening the `maxPwdAge` property.

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746343(v=VS.85).aspx, the `PasswordExpirationDate` property is read-write.